# Displaying a .wkt file as a multilinestring in three dimensions with Python

Tags: python, mayavi, multilinestring

I have a .wkt file that is multilinestring and has 3D data, I want to display it in Python, and I used the following code for this purpose.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.wkt import loads
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString

def display_3d_wkt(file_path):
    # Read .wkt file into a GeoDataFrame
    geometry = loads(open(file_path).read())
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[MultiLineString], geometry_column='geometry')

    # Create a 3D plot using Mayavi
    from mayavi import mlab

    # Extract coordinates from MultiLineString
    x, y, z = zip(*geometry.coords.xy)

    # Create a Mayavi 3D plot
    mlab.figure()
    mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, tube_radius=0.1)

    # Show the 3D plot
    mlab.show()

# Specify the .wkt file path
wkt_file_path = "expanded_skeleton4.wkt"

# Display the content of the .wkt file in 3D
display_3d_wkt(wkt_file_path)
```

And I get the following error. What should I do to fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzttt.jpg)

I also used this code:

```
mayavi import mlab
from shapely.wkt import loads

def display_3d_wkt(file_path):
    # Read .wkt file into a Shapely geometry
    geometry = loads(open(file_path).read())

    # Check if the geometry is a collection of geometries (multi-part)
    if geometry.geom_type.startswith('Multi'):
        # Iterate over each part of the multi-part geometry
        for part in geometry:
            display_3d_part(part)
    else:
        # Display the single-part geometry
        display_3d_part(geometry)

def display_3d_part(geometry):
    # Extract coordinates from the geometry
    x, y, z = zip(*geometry.coords.xy)

    # Create a Mayavi 3D plot
    mlab.figure()
    mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, tube_radius=0.1)

    # Show the 3D plot
    mlab.show()

# Specify the .wkt file path
wkt_file_path = "path/to/your/file.wkt"

# Display the content of the .wkt file in 3D
display_3d_wkt(wkt_file_path)
```

And I got the following error:type error: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable